# styling inline images and captions

Tags: html, css, image, inline, caption

The following code acts as a section allowing a user to scroll through a host of images horizontally. I want to place text undderneath each image . I'm having serious trouble doing this and would be very grateful for any sugestions

```
<div class="favored" style="background-color: #F8FFFA;overflow-x:scroll; white-space: nowrap;" >
    <span>
        <img id='<?echo $user_id;?>' src="<?echo$image_path?>">
        <caption for="<?echo $user_id?>" style='position: bottom;'><?echo$first_name?></caption>
    </span>
    <span>
        <img id='<?echo $user_id;?>' src="<?echo$image_path?>">
        <caption for="<?echo $user_id?>" style='position: bottom;'><?echo$first_name?></caption>
    </span>        <span>
        <img id='<?echo $user_id;?>' src="<?echo$image_path?>">
        <caption for="<?echo $user_id?>" style='position: bottom;'><?echo$first_name?></caption>
    </span>        <span>
        <img id='<?echo $user_id;?>' src="<?echo$image_path?>">
        <caption for="<?echo $user_id?>" style='position: bottom;'><?echo$first_name?></caption>
    </span>
</div>
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Post a [mcve] please. We don't need your PHP but we will need your CSS.

Answer (score 0):

[Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) to the rescue!

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

ul li {
  width: 350px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x100">
    <p>caption</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x100">
    <p>caption</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x100">
    <p>caption</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x100">
    <p>caption</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x100">
    <p>caption</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x100">
    <p>caption</p>
  </li>

</ul>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation of why/how this code helps the OP. This will help provide an answer future viewers can learn from. See [this Meta question and its answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/256359/215552) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I see your code . And I exactly know what you want . So I copy this code directly from one of my projects .

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>

<head>
    <title>Untitled</title>
    <style type="text/css">

        .block-scroller {
            width: 100%;
            height: 49.5vw;     /* It should has it */
            clear: both;
            margin: 0.5% 0;
        }

        #scroller {
            width: 100%;
            height: 39.5vw;     /* It should has it */
            overflow-x: scroll;     /* It make the block scroll */
        }

        #scrolled-parent {
            width: 300%;     /* It should has it */
            height: 100%;
        }

        .scrolled {
            width: calc(98.5% / 6) !important;     /* 98.5% means the 100% - "all of the scrolled blocks margins" and 6 means the six block that we add in html */
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0 0.125%;
            float: left;
            background: url(http://placehold.it/600x500) black no-repeat center /cover;
        }

        .scrolled p {
            width: 100%;
            line-height: 10vw;
            background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.7);     /* The background color of captions */
            color: white;
            font-family: sans-serif;
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 1em;
            margin: 0;
        }

        p#class-title {
            width: 100%;
            line-height: 10vw;
            background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
            color: white;
            font-family: sans-serif;
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 1em;
            margin: 0;
        }

    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="block-scroller">
        <div id="scroller">
            <div id="scrolled-parent">
                <div id="class301" class="scrolled"><p>301</p></div>
                <div id="class302" class="scrolled"><p>302</p></div>
                <div id="class303" class="scrolled"><p>303</p></div>
                <div id="class304" class="scrolled"><p>304</p></div>
                <div id="class305" class="scrolled"><p>305</p></div>
                <div id="class306" class="scrolled"><p>306</p></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <p id="class-title">Class</p>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

You see it has a nice transparent caption and a group name . Actually I create it for a mobile app interface but I showed the `width`, `height`, `background-image` of the blocks and captions `background-color` .
TIP : In the body section on line "62" `.block-scroller` is the parent of the hole codes.
On line "63" `#scroller` is the `div` that has the scrolled `div` in it .
On line "64" `#scrolled-parent` has the hole images with its captions in it and it is the only `div` that is scrolling .
And the `.scrolled` blocks are the images with it captions .